# Tensor product of fundamental representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple complex Lie algebra. Let $V_1,\cdots, V_n$ be the fundamental representations (the irreducible ones with fundamental weights $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n$). Take a $k$-tensor product of these representations:  $V_{\lambda_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes V_{\lambda_k}$ (with each $\lambda_i\in\{\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n\}$).

Decompose this product into irreducible representations. Let $\lambda=\sum n_i\omega_i$ be the highest weight of such a simple summand. Can we conclude $\sum n_i\leq k$?

I can show it holds for type $A_n$ and $C_n$.

Comment: Can we not conclude immediately that $\sum n_i = k$ for the "highest highest" weight? The tensor product of $V_\lambda$ and $V_\mu$ contains $V_{\mu + \lambda}$ and all other irreducible subrepresentations have lower highest weight. Extending this to $V_{\lambda_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes V_{\lambda_k}$ we see that the highest weight present overall is $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k$ (so all other highest weights are lower than this) from which the result you want follows.

Comment: That is true. But some lower weight of the form ($\sum n_i w_i -$ simple roots) may have larger $\sum n_i$.

Comment: Ah good point and indeed playing around with some examples produces a counter example: in $D_5$, $V_{\omega_1}\otimes V_{\omega_2}\otimes V_{\omega_3}\otimes V_{\omega_5}$ contains a subrepresentation of the form $V_{2\omega_1 + \omega_4+ 2\omega_5}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually one can show that if $\sum n_i \lambda_i$ is a highest weight in a $k$-tensor product of fundamental representations, we have $\sum n_i\leq \beta \cdot k$ for some $\beta$ uniquely determined by the simple type of $\mathfrak{g}$.